# Can't connect to MongoDB database and collection through class variables

Tags: python, mongodb, class, python-2.7

Just as a preface, I understand that there are easier ways to accomplish much of what i'm trying to do, and the following question is for purposes of learning how to build classes and instantiate a database connection within that class.

I'm building a class that right now just takes in two variables; the name of MongoDB database, and the collection name from that database. I am trying to instantiate the connection of this database and the collection in the **init** function of this class. The problem I am having is that the **init** function is connecting to the database of the actual name of the variable instead of the variable's actual assignment. More specifically, if I instantiate,

```
>>>salesChar = MongoDumps("sales","char")
```

and then I call,

```
>>>salesChar.db.name
```

it will instead connect to the "dBase" (the name of the variable) database instead of the "salesChar" (the assignment of the dBase variable) database. Please view code below,

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient

class MongoDumps():
"""Data Dumping into MongoDB"""

    def __init__(self, dBase, dumpCollection):
        self.dBase = dBase
        self.dumpCollection = dumpCollection
        client = MongoClient()
        self.db = client.dBase
        self.collection = self.db.dumpCollection
```

I've tried a combination of strategies and none seem to work with a similar result in each one. Are there certain limitations to using assignments in a class? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is `client.dBase`?

Comment: dBase is the variable that I am trying to pass its assignment to the MongoDB client to access that specific db. For example, if 'dBase = sales', I'm trying to connect to 'client.sales'. The problem i'm having is that it's connecting to 'client.dBase'. In other words, it seems that the assignment to the dBase variable in this case is just "dBase" (instead of sales).

Comment: I understand what `dBase` is, but what is `client.dBase`? The fact that the two has the same name does not make them the same variable. One is a local parameter (`dbase`), you also assign this to a class variable (`self.dBase = dBase`), but then you create the `client` and it too has `client.dBase`, which is not the same, hence my question.

Comment: As I understand it, that is how you connect to a mongoDB instance. client is just a variable assigned to the instance of MongoClient(), and client.dBase is my way of connecting to the specific database I want to connect to. Replacing the dBase variable with whatever it is assigned to... really just following this documentation [pymongo](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html)

Comment: No, `client.dBase` is accessing a field or property on `client` that is *named* `dBase`, it does not use the content of your variable `dBase` to access things on `client`, so it is *not* trying to read `client.sales`. See the answer left by Sergey below for how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to get property by string. As documentation says, `getattr(x, 'foobar')` is equivalent to `x.foobar`. Your code should look like:

```
class MongoDumps():
    def __init__(self, dBase, dumpCollection):
        self.dBase = dBase
        self.dumpCollection = dumpCollection
        client = MongoClient()
        self.db = getattr(client, dBase)
        self.collection = getattr(self.db, dumpCollection)
```

Then you can use this class to get collection by name:

```
salesChar = MongoDumps("sales", "char")
first = salesChar.collection.find_one()
```